# cakephp / webtechnick's : share button hides like button and comments

Tags: facebook, cakephp, share

my issue might look a strange a little bit.
i'm working on a cakephp website in which i want to integrate facebook comments, like, and share functions. i'm using for that [Webtechnick's Facebook plug-in](http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/238/Facebook_Plugin_v2_0_Graph_System), and i think this far everything is doing great. except one thing.
whene i call comments and like:

```
<?php $facebook->comments(); ?>
<?php $facebook->like(); ?>
```

it works and i have my share and like buttons, but when i call

```
<?php $facebook->share(); ?>
<?php $facebook->comments(); ?>
<?php $facebook->like(); ?>
```

only the share button is displayed. It's like if the share button hides likes and comments
not sure if this is clear enough, I know it's a strange problem.

If anybody has experienced something similar to this please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off using the social plugin versions of these three.  I'd recomment you start with the HTML5 versions and go from there.

See:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ (does both like and send)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: I agree, using a cake plugin for this task seems unnecessary.